# How many ways to construct subspaces of a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $q$ be a prime power and $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, $\mathbb{F}_q$ be two finite fields. We can view  $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ as an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

How many ways are there to construct $\mathbb{F}_q$-subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$?

Comment: Presumably, any such subspace is to inherit vector addition and scalar multiplication from the standard operations on $\Bbb F_{q^n}$, right?

Comment: You want to know the number of $\Bbb{F}_q$-vector spaces $\subset \Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ ? It is called the [grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian), you count the number of $d$ linearly independent vectors then you divide by the number of elements of $GL_d(\Bbb{F}_q)$, see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12622.pdf)

Comment: @reuns No. I want to know as many as possible methods to construct subspaces.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you are right.

Comment: The set of subspaces is called the grassmannian. You can list all the subspaces by listing all the sets of vectors, the difficulty is to not list two times the same subspace, this is called the grassmannian ($Gr(d,F_q^n)=\{A\in F_q^{n\times d},rank(A)=d\}/ GL_d(F_q)$)